# Moving HTML elements while css transform : scale is applied

Tags: javascript, css-transforms

I have a `div` element, which i scaled such that it fits my `viewport` using

```
-webkit-transform:scale(sx, sy)
```

Now i need to animate other elements within this scaled div,

If i don't apply scale transform and change top, left style of element with `transition:1s` then everything works fine. But with scale transform on, i can't find right XY coordinate to
move elements.

So what is the right way to compute left, top with css transform applied.

Comment: The best method I can suggest would be to have a 100% transparent duplicate that instantly scales, then use that to calculate where elements need to move to.  If that makes sense.

Comment: so your saying i keep two copies of elements, one scaled and other non-scaled, compute coordinates from non-scaled and apply to scaled one and that will work fine ??

Comment: I have done something similar in my pages - I'd suggest not complete copies (for instance, you probably don't want to load images twice, etc - just put in placeholders) but if you compute from non-scaled and apply those to the scaled you should at least have the right numbers.

Comment: okay let me quickly try and get back to you.

Comment: no, does not work! there should be some way to find scaled xy coordinates right??

Comment: I'm not confident we're communicating 'scaled' and 'nonscaled' properly - I would, when the animation to scale the div to fill your viewport starts, instantly scale a copy of the div (with transparency) and calculate based off that one to find what coordinates things need to go to.  Is that what you tried?

Comment: i captured the XY coordinate where i want div to move before scaling is done, then i scale it and after that apply captured XY to my div. but i t wont move where i want it to.

Comment: Try posting a fiddle, so I can see what you mean.

Comment: @Helpful your approach worked, i cached all the non scaled coordinates, and then applied for my movements.